# sql select thru multiple postgres databases

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there a way to create a select statement that would retrieve data from multiple database in postgre?

i was thinking it would be something like this:

select * from dbname1.table1, dbname2.table2 where  dbname1.table1.column1 = dbname2.table2.column1

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the "[dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html)" contrib module.

OTOH it's possible that you treat the databases in a PostgreSQL cluster as equivalent to the databases in... let's say MySQL. Which is incorrect - the PostgreSQL databases contain schemas and those are the equivalent of the databases in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/manage-ag-overview.html):

> It is not possible to access more than
>   one database per connection.

Update: but see [Milen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778128/sql-select-thru-multiple-postgres-databases/778183#778183).